# Convert ASCII to UTF-8 along with hexadecimal `/x` notation - PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, hex, ascii, utf

**What I want**

```
\ud83d\ude1c //Emoji Unicode
```

To covert in

```
\xF0\x9F\x98\x83 //Hexadecimal string with /x notation
```

**What I know so far**

`ASCII` is a subset of `UTF-8` == `true`

I've tried many listed solutions but nothing worked for me. Actually I'm having an complete array of `hex` EMOJI elements and once I'll have `hex` value, I can pick correspondence `png` of that emoji.  Any single help can lead me in a way.

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: ASCII is actually pretty much irrelevant here. What you have is a string which contains Unicode escape sequences (`\u....`), which actually don't have much to do with ASCII *nor* Unicode. Perhaps you can clarify where those came from? Then you want to convert those into an actual UTF-8 encoded byte sequence representing the emoji represented by those escape sequences, and output that byte sequence in hex (escape) notation…

Comment: @deceze actually I'm working for the webservices. mobile clients will store the unicode escape in db for their simple usage. They simply decode the unicode and its automatically converts in good looking emoji. But in the web, I need to show the emojis like whatsapp, twitter are showing

Comment: @deceze I've string with unicode escaped its right. I can simply decode this and show the emoji in web but it does not look much great as per Iphone or android. So I found a php lib which is somehow showing emoji png from it's hex value. So I thought first If I can get the hex value of unicode escape then I can move forward